# Convert object to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to convert an object like this

```
{ "1": [ { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" } ], "5": [ { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" } ] }
```

to an array like this

```
[{ "1": [ { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" } ], "5": [ { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" } ] }]
```

I tried using JSON.parse but didn't work. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: I'm sorry… spot the difference?! Is the only change an additional `[]` around the entire thing?

Comment: Yea, has been fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in an array.

```
array = [object];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const object  = { "1": [ { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" } ], "5": [ { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" } ] }


const array = Array(object);
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize first as follows:

```
var obj = { "1": [ { "Id": "1", "name": "xxx", "age": "22" }, { "Id": "1", "name": "yyy", "age": "15" } ], "5": [ { "Id": "5", "name": "zzz", "age": "59" } ] };
var arr = [];
```

and then you can do one of the following:

1. `arr = [obj];`
2. `arr.push(obj);`

Answer (score 0):

Assign the first object to a variable, say temp1.
Now,

```
var yourarray = new Array(temp1);
```

Done!